# Possible infection? Alot of unknown connections

Tags: networking, malware

I watched a video a while ago about some guy getting infected through some exploits and all those things. He believed he was infected by doing `sudo netstat -natp`
Which displayed a bunch of unknown connections like me. He later terminated this *possible infection.*

I am no expert with this type of thing so I wanted someone who knew more about this than me to help me figure out what all these unknown connections are or what can be causing this.

I used `sudo netstat -natp`with all programs closed.

I Xed out parts of the addresses just incase they important to identify me. Although, if you guys think it's okay I can uncensor them.

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1048/dnsmasq    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      821/cupsd       
tcp        0      0 192.168.2.XX:34832       XXX.58.XXX.XX:80        TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 192.168.2.XX:34826       XXX.58.XXX.XX:80        TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 192.168.2.XX:44316       XX.125.XXX.XX:443       TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 192.168.2.XX:35948       XX.125.XXX.XXX:80       TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 192.168.2.3:54768       XX.125.XXX.XX:443       TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 192.168.2.XX:57882       XX.125.XXX.XX:443       TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 192.168.2.XX:49064       XX.10.XXX.XX:443        TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 192.168.2.XX:48852       XX.230.XX.XXX:443       TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 192.168.2.XX:33430       XXX.58.XXX.XXX:443      TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 192.168.2.XX:44788       XXX.58.XXX.XXX:443      TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 192.168.2.XX:57914       XX.125.XXX.XX:443       TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 192.168.2.3:47418       XXX.58.XXX.XX:443       TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 192.168.2.XX:36346       XX.125.XXX.XXX:443      TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp        0      0 192.168.2.XX:57886       XX.125.XXX.XX:443       TIME_WAIT   -               
tcp6       0      0 ::1:63X                 :::*                    LISTEN      821/cupsd       
tcp6       1      0 ::1:579XX               ::1:63X                 CLOSE_WAIT  856/cups-browsed
tcp6       1      0 ::1:579XX               ::1:63X                 CLOSE_WAIT  856/cups-browsed
```

Comment: you can't get infected by `sudo netstat ...` unless netstat is the malware.

Comment: I know. I believe it just shows what connections are established which when I checked it displayed a bunch of unknown connections. I would also like to note with I checked the connection it pointed to Google but I don't have any of their services running on my PC